# Prepared statements in Ballerina

Tags: prepared-statement, ballerina

Prepared statements help to prevent SQL injection attacks.

I tried to find about prepared statements in Ballerina. But there is no documentation on it.

I want to know how to implement prepared statements in Ballerina if ballerina supports prepared statements or how to prevent SQL injection attacks if ballerina doesn't.

Comment: The [official Ballerina documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/sql.html) makes mention of JDBC, which implies that it is not a database tool itself, but rather likely supports some number of actual databases.  So, for example, if your underlying database be MySQL, then you should search for "MySQL prepared statements."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL injection prevention is achieved through a taint analysis mechanism at compilation time itself.

Please refer [this example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/taint-checking.html) for more information on this.